# JavaFX bind list size to this.setTitle()

Tags: java, list, javafx, data-binding, observable

I want the title of my notes-program to change whenever my list (notes) changes. To achieve this I wanted to bind an IntegerProperty to the size of my list, but it says:

> The method bind(ObservableValue<? extends Number>) in the type Property is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Does this mean I should cast the size from int to a Number (tried it but there was another problem) or is there an even easier solution?

```
public class Notes extends Stage {
    ObservableList<String> notes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Notes() {
        this.setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        IntegerProperty size = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        size.bind(this.notes.size());

        this.setTitle(String.format("Notes (%d)", size.getValue()));

        final Scene scene = new Scene(this.createRootPane());
        this.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. that snippet doesn't make sense to me: why do you try to bind anything to whatever when don't use it after (except that one-time access to get its value)? Do you want to bind the title to the notes.size()? If so, look at the Bindings class, it has utility methods to create list-related bindings

Comment: Specifically, see https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...) and https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#size(javafx.collections.ObservableList)

Answer (score 1):

Just bind your title property to the [list size’s](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#size(javafx.collections.ObservableList)) [asString](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#asString(java.lang.String)) binding:

```
titleProperty().bind(Bindings.size(notes).asString("Notes (%d)"));
```